# Apache rewrite proxy flag changes client IP address

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using an htaccess file to redirect all subdirectories to the index.php file and pass the directory name as a variable. I'm using a proxy [P] flag to prevent the URL from redirecting/changing in the visitor's browser.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])(.*)$ https://domain.com/index.php?user=$1 [P,L,NC]
```

However, the index page uses $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] to track the IP address of the visitor. This works fine when I test the root domain, but the subdirectories all show up as the same internal IP address (i.e. due to the proxy).

How can I have it both ways? i.e. keep the URL static in the browser but get the true client IP in both cases?

Comment: If you want the address in the browser to stay the same, then simply _don’t_ do an _external_ redirect – make it an internal redirect, and scrap the proxy nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

Apache sets some extra headers to help you handle this. You'll need to modify the backend to check for the [X-Forwarded-For](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers) header in addition (or instead) of the client IP. Depending on why you're checking, it might be good to only check that header if the request is coming from your proxy's IP, since the header can be spoofed.

Answer (score 0):

James - thanks... that set me headed in the right direction. For those who need it, after updating the config the PHP call to get the proxy forwarded IP is $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].